# MATLAB vision.ShapeInserter() function gives warning about CustomBorderColor attribute

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to create two shapes for inserting into a video frame. Whenever

```
blueBox = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Rectangles',...
                          'BorderColor','Custom',...
                          'CustomBorderColor',uint8([0 0 255]));

greenCircle = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Circles',...
                          'BorderColor','Custom',...
                          'Fill', true,...
                          'CustomBorderColor',uint8([200 255 50]));
```

Whenever I run the script MATLAB warns me about `CustomBorderColor` property. The strange point is that it gives warning message for `greenCircle` not for `blueBox`.

> Warning: The CustomBorderColor property is not relevant in this
>   configuration of the System object.
>
> > In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\pvParse.p>pvParse
> >     at 25   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.parseInputs
> >     at 639   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.setProperties
> >     at 138   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\vision\vision+vision\ShapeInserter.p>ShapeInserter.ShapeInserter
> >     at 254

Then I tried to change the code as the following:

```
greenCircle =vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Circles', ...
                                  'Fill', true, ...
                                  'FillColor', 'Custom', ...
                                  'CustomFillColor', uint8([0 1 3]), ...
                                  'BorderColor','Custom', ...
                                  'CustomBorderColor',uint8([200 255 50]));
```

But still getting that warning message:

> Warning: The CustomBorderColor property is not relevant in this
>   configuration of the System object.
>
> > In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\pvParse.p>pvParse
> >     at 25   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.parseInputs
> >     at 639   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\system+matlab+system\SystemProp.p>SystemProp.setProperties
> >     at 138   In C:\Program
> >     Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\vision\vision+vision\ShapeInserter.p>ShapeInserter.ShapeInserter
> >     at 254

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this warning because you have `'Fill'` set to `true` for `greenCircle`. You can use `'FillColor'` and `'CustomFillColor'` to set the color of a filled circle.

Also, if you have MATLAB version R2014a or later you can use the `insertShape` function instead of `vision.ShapeInserter`. The function is easier to use.

Comment: Does this mean I cannot have a yellow bordered red circle?

Comment: You can, if you use two shape inserters. First you draw a filled red circle, and then an unfilled yellow circle on top of it.